# Галерея изображений

Tags: jquery

Есть галерея изображений на jQuery (вот [демо](http://ruseller.com/lessons/les1275/demo/index.html)). Описание к изображениям выводится в той же рамке, что и изображение ( http://SSMaker.ru/25fd84e8/ ), а хотелось бы вывести описание снизу. То есть, сейчас так http://SSMaker.ru/669724d9/ + http://SSMaker.ru/9a06ccb4/ , а хотелось бы так http://SSMaker.ru/55af8d3a/ + http://SSMaker.ru/67d14454/ .

И удалить из галереи вот эту возможность http://SSMaker.ru/60b72b8b/ .Надеюсь найдутся те, кто сможет мне помочь или хотя бы что-нибудь подскажут. Заранее всем спасибо.

Comment: Сомневаюсь что кто-то будет пересматривать код из 1k строк. К тому же пара ссылок битые!

Comment: А не проще было дать ссылку на страницу, где вы эти эксперименты проводите?

Comment: а я и так дал ссылку на демо.

все остальное к сожалению уже удалили и наверное уже ни кто не поможет. 

хм... странно, если одному лень помочь - не факт, что другие не помогут. зачем сразу минусовать и удалять...

Answer (score 1):

Описание выводится как вы сами видите в div с классом `rg-caption-wrapper`. Этот элемент как и другие некоторые добавляется из шаблона, который указан в начале страницы

```
 <script id="img-wrapper-tmpl" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
 ...
```

Измените там иерархию div'ов и получите ту иерархию какая вам нужна.

По поводу кнопок смотрите файл gallery.js. Там в функции init есть вызов добавления этих кнопок

```
// Добавляем опции
_addViewModes();
```

Закомментируйте этот вызов и их не будет.

Comment: Хоть кто то ответил )

div с классом rg-caption-wrapper вставлен в head и /head.

        <script id="img-wrapper-tmpl" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl"> 
            <div class="rg-caption-wrapper">
                    <div class="rg-caption" style="display: none;">
                        <p></p>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </script>

Но при загрузке страницы он получается между body. и если его просто так взять и переставить - описание изображения вообще не выводится.

Comment: Он вставлен в head для плагина jquery.tmpl.min.js, который этот код размещает 
в коде страницы. соответственно вам нужно (попробовать) поменять тот код на:

     <div class="rg-image-wrapper">
       ...
     </div>
     <div class="rg-caption-wrapper">
       <div class="rg-caption" style="display:none;">
         <p></p>
       </div>
     </div>

т.е. оставить его в head, просто поменять иерархию относительно rg-image-wrapper.

ЗЫ Вообще вам не помешает разобраться с работой подключенных плагинов и проч чтоб понять механизмы которые там срабатывают и в каком порядке.